# React can't print the form data in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, flask, console.log

So, this is my `App.js` file and the next picture is what I get when I hit submit. I want to get all the entered values to be printed on console but that's not happening.

I am also using Flask as backend and I want to get all these data into `app.py` so how to do that ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
 

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        petalLen: "",
        petalWid: "",
        sepalLen: "",
        sepalWid: "",
    };
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
}
handleOnChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event);

    for (let [key, value] of data.entries()) {
        console.log(key, value);
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Deploy Models for Humans </h1>
            <Form>
                <Container>
                    <Row className="Rr">
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Label>Petal Length</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                name="petalLen"
                                value={this.state.petalLen}
                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                placeholder="Petal Length"
                            />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label>Petal Width</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="petalWid"
                                    value={this.state.petalWid}
                                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                    placeholder="Petal Width"
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label>Sepal Length</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="sepalLen"
                                    value={this.state.sepalLen}
                                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                    placeholder="Sepal Length"
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label>Sepal Width</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="sepalWid"
                                    value={this.state.sepalWid}
                                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                                    placeholder="Sepal Width"
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Container>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

After I hit submit :

[image: enter image descrption here]

Comment: The button click event won't work with FormData. FormData takes *form* as the argument, not click event

Comment: you have to manually add either values in form data or add form arguement as @d_bhatnagar mentioned

Comment: instead of using the handleSubmit function on Button click, use it in the ```<Form>``` as ```<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>```

Comment: Okay, so how to print anything that the user types in the form on console ?

Comment: Oh right right @d_bhatnagar let me try that

Comment: If you want to print the data in the console.. no need to use the form data, you can also do console.log(this.state) in your click handler as you are updating your state with the values..

Comment: Ya @d_bhatnagar now the error is not their, so now how to get print these or get the data